# Load Angular 2 component in specific part

Tags: angular

My goal is to load tables components inside panel component, so basically

I have 3 components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: '<h1>Title!</h1><div #child></div>',
})
export class ParentComponent {
  title = 'Parent'
}
```

And

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: '<div>I'm the {{title}}</div>',
})
export class ChildComponent {
  title = 'Child'
}


@Component({
  selector: 'other-child',
  template: '<div>I'm the {{title}}</div>',
})
export class OtherChildComponent {
  title = 'Other'
}
```

How can i load any component in the parent div marked as #child?, something like

```
load('#child',OtherChildComponent)
```

Comment: You could do something like `<div #{{selector}}>`, and then set the `selector` in your parent controller;  This a pretty rigid design though, overall....

Comment: you should consider designing around using `ngComponentOutlet` instead...  https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/11235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use your child selector in parent template

```
<h1>Title!</h1>
<child></child> <!-- will contains <div>I'm the child</div>  -->
<other-child></other-child> <!-- will contains <div>I'm the other</div> -->
```

Comment: I want to load dinamiclly

Comment: ok, you should specify that in your question. Anyway, its seems like NgComponentOutlet is what you are looking for https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgComponentOutlet-directive.html